# How to output Name or DisplayName of members of shared mailbox in Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to output a list of members of a shared mailbox by selecting displayName. I have the below script which will output the users userPrincipalName(UPN), the problem with this is our users login with an ID number, for example when I run the script I get the output: `666777@mycompany.com` I would like to output the actual name of the user so I don't have to go to Active Directory and type in `666777` to find out the name of the user. The script I use is:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "NorthOffice@mycompany.com" -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Select-Object User
```

The above script outputs for example:

```
User
----
666777@mycompany.com
```

I've tried using: `| Select-Object displayName` but these properties show as empty/blank

Anyone know a way around this?

**EDIT**

I've found a way to do it but it's quite long winded:

I export the results of the script into a csv

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "NorthOffice@mycompany.com" -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Select-Object User | Export-csv c:\myfolder\NorthOffice.csv
```

I then change the header of the csv to userPrincipalName and save. I then import the csv and run a 'ForEach' like below:

```
Import-Csv C:\myfolder\NorthOffice.csv | ForEach { 
   Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userPrincipalName )'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName | Select Name,SamAccountName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\myfolder\NorthOfficeOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Does anyone know a quicker way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "NorthOffice@mycompany.com" | select -ExpandProperty User | findstr /v /c:"NT AUTHORITY\SELF" | foreach {Get-ADUser -Identity ($_ -split "@")[0] -Properties * | select displayName} | sort
```

`Get-ADUser` won't accept UserPrincipalName as Identity (but it will accept SamAccountName), so we split the SMTP address at the "@" to get just the first part.  ***(This, of course, assumes that the UPN and SMTP address are the same, and the first part of the SMTP address is the same as the SamAccountName.)***

If this does not work for you, and you don't need to drop back to AD, you can just use `Get-Mailbox` to resolve the DisplayName directly from Exchange:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "NorthOffice@mycompany.com" | select -ExpandProperty User | findstr /v /c:"NT AUTHORITY\SELF" | foreach {Get-Mailbox -Identity $_ | select displayName} | sort
```